# How to parse a semi-JSON file?

Tags: json, parsing, logging

I have a server log that looks like:

```
<timestamp> <process>: Requesting information from the server with header: {
    userID: "myname"
    age: "20" 
} 
and body: {
myotherinfo = {
    education = undergrad
    job = engineer
    hobbies = [piano, tenis]
    }
}
```

This file only looks like JSON, but it lacks "`,`" separator, and contains a bunch of sentence strings. How do I parse this string such that I can access it like a real JSON file? For example, when I want to type "`header`" and it should return all the properties of headers. I should also be able to type "`header.age`" etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  here's a one-line "sed" script that probably does most of what you want:: `sed -n '/header/,/}/p' myfile.txt`.

Comment: @paulsm4 Can you briefly explain your sed command?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you basically have two choices:

1) Write a script in your favorite language to parse the file: Perl, Java, C#, Python - whatever

... or ...

2) Use something like [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to create your own parser.

Here are a few tutorials for the latter:

- http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/bison.html
- http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html
- [Lex & Yacc Tutorial, Tom Niemann](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/)